# How to rebind XON/XOFF keys?

Tags: bash, tty

I put `stty -ixon -ixoff` in my `.bashrc` so I can use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to search the bash history forward ([here there is a text about it](http://ruslanspivak.com/2010/11/25/bash-history-incremental-search-forward/)). However, I sometimes used <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to *really* send the XOFF signal to the TTY, and would like to be able to still do it but using some other key combination. Is it possible to bind some other key combination in such a way it would send the XOFF signal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not on key combinations but on characters. It can be done with `stty stop` and `stty start`. Like:

```
stty stop '^T'
```

Above `^T` can be either the two characters `^` and `T` or that `^T` character (which you can enter by typing the lnext character (usually `^V`) followed by <kbd>Ctrl-T</kbd>).